# Error in Python When Loading Workbook Using Openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm very simply trying to load a workbook in Python using openpyxl.  I'm using the code below, but I keep getting an error saying "ValueError: Value must be one of {'data', 'field', 'selection'}".

`openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = r"my_file")`

The file has several tables of data grabbed with Power Query, and some pivot tables and pivot charts.  I have a feeling that somehow may be the issue, since I am able to load very simple workbooks using this code, but not this one for some reason.  Is the content of the workbook somehow causing the error?

The full traceback of the error is below:

```
~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
    316                         data_only, keep_links)
--> 317     reader.read()
    318     return reader.wb

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in read(self)
    277         self.read_theme()
    278         apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
--> 279         self.read_worksheets()
    280         self.parser.assign_names()
    281         if not self.read_only:

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in read_worksheets(self)
    263                 src = self.archive.read(pivot_path)
    264                 tree = fromstring(src)
--> 265                 pivot = TableDefinition.from_tree(tree)
    266                 pivot.cache = self.parser.pivot_caches[pivot.cacheId]
    267                 ws.add_pivot(pivot)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
     81             if hasattr(desc, 'from_tree'):
     82                 #descriptor manages conversion
---> 83                 obj = desc.from_tree(el)
     84             else:
     85                 if hasattr(desc.expected_type, "from_tree"):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py in from_tree(self, node)
     83 
     84     def from_tree(self, node):
---> 85         return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
     86 
     87 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     83 
     84     def from_tree(self, node):
---> 85         return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
     86 
     87 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
    101                 attrib[tag] = obj
    102 
--> 103         return cls(**attrib)
    104 
    105 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\pivot\table.py in __init__(self, scope, type, priority, pivotAreas, extLst)
    478                  extLst=None,
    479                 ):
--> 480         self.scope = scope
    481         self.type = type
    482         self.priority = priority

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py in __set__(self, instance, value)
    126     def __set__(self, instance, value):
    127         if value not in self.values:
--> 128             raise ValueError(self.__doc__)
    129         super(Set, self).__set__(instance, value)
    130 

ValueError: Value must be one of {'data', 'field', 'selection'}
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace tf the error?

Comment: It's too long for a comment but I can add it in pieces if you want...

Comment: I added the traceback in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem lies with the values in the file. As you also mentioned this

> since I am able to load very simple workbooks using this code, but not this one for some reason.

This simply means that it expects values of the suggested type in the error-trace. The scope of the values must be within theses `ValueError: Value must be one of {'data', 'field', 'selection'}`. If not, it will throw the error. The likely throw point of the error is from [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/pivot/table.html#ConditionalFormat).

Solve it by opening the file and checking that the values are as required and that there aren't any unwanted characters (left unintentionally anywhere in the file).

Comment: Yes, I think that's what is happening.  I will take a look through my Excel workbook to see if there is something in there that is causing this error.  I'm not really sure what the part of the link that you sent was meaning though.  Can you explain what exactly that was?

Comment: @David that is the code that was responsible for the error. if you look at the scope variable, that defines the values that are acceptable. When it's not true, it throws the error